# Raised-Cosine filter - design

Tags: filters, dsp-core, finite-impulse-response

I have a requirement to design bandpass Raised-Cosine filter with the magnitude and phase response as outlined in the picture below. I have read some literature online (still learning DSP) and I have found some formula in time and frequency domain for Raised-Cosine LPF only. I have a bandpass specification. I have to implement design in C++ code. What is the best way to design Raised-Cosine filter? How I can obtain filter's coefficients in the function of number of taps? How I specify the desired phase? I don't want to use MATLAB.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your requirements and the plots are more confusing than helpful. I don't think a raised cosine filter can possibly have a phase like your purple curve or a magnitude like the green line below. Furthermore, that magnitude response does not correspond to a bandpass filter. Please clarify.

Comment: Magnitude is for bandpass filter, F1 = 1kHz, F2=18kHz. Maybe if you can indicate how to calculate h(n) for raise cosine would help?